# find all form names on a page using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get all form names exists on a page using jquery??? can I use jquery input selector to find all forms on a page.
for example I have a form on page like below

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="">
<input type="text" name="inputname" />
</form>
```

now i want to find the form name "searchForm" using jquery. so how can i do this??

please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read this: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Your question is unclear: the first sentence sounds like you want to use jQuery to get a list of all form names on the page, but then you say you want to find "searchForm", implying you want to select a form that you already know the name of.

To get all form names and store them in an array:

```
var names = [];
$("form").each(function() {
   names.push(this.name);
});
```

To select a form you already know the name of:

```
$('form[name="searchForm"]')

// or if the name is in a variable:
var name = "searchForm";
$('form[name="' + name + '"]')
```

Or you can just select by id:

```
$('#searchForm')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form").map(function(idx, form){
    return form.name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$('form[name="searchForm"]')
```

Using vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName('searchForm')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all forms with the name of searchForm your selector would be:

```
$('form[name="searchForm"]');
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('form[name="searchForm"]')
```

Uses the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector